# How to remove/ignore most recent kernel?

Tags: kernel, grub2

After the most recent kernel upgrade, my system hangs during boot.  Since my machine seems especially persnickety about pulling up the grub menu*, what is the best way to set the previous kernel as the default until the next upgrade?

*I have to hit ESC at *exactly* the right moment, which usually means rebooting several times until I get it.

Comment: To see the Grub menu at boot it is recommended to press and hold the `Shift` key during boot.

Answer (score 3):

An nice application is available in the Software Centre which should help you.  Its called "Startup Manager".

It looks like this:
[image]

Choose the Kernel you wish to default to in the drop-down list and then click Close to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Once started with the old kernel, modify your `/etc/default/grub` with

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="title"
```

where "title" is the exact menu title of the kernel you want to start.
You can somehow obtain this with

```
grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and you can live until the next kernel upgrade, when you can set back `GRUB_DEFAULT` to 0 or choose another "title".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Where do we find the title if /boot/grub/grub.cfg does not exist?

Comment: @MarkStosberg: if you don't have `grub.cfg` it means that you don't have grub installed or you have the old grub, so this tip do not apply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @enzotib. I found that if I run 'update-grub', the file is created.