# How Can I Roll Back a Kernel Update?

Tags: networking, kernel

An update for Ubuntu was available today and it installed the generic kernel 2.6.38.11.26.

After doing so networking is no longer functioning correctly. My Acer Aspire 4520 has an Nvidia Network card and an Atheros wireless chipset which was functioning properly before the update.

Now when I boot neither are functioning properly. Wireless Networking is still a selectable option but even when enabled the options for selecting a network is grayed out. The Ethernet connection will activate but only after about 3-5 minutes after booting to the desktop.

How can I fix this or roll back to the previous kernel? This is a serious bug and I'm fairly certain I'm not the only one with this issue.

Comment: Here is a simple method to pin the kernel back to the previous until you find an answer to make your wireless work with the latest kernel:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/40780/how-to-remove-ignore-most-recent-kernel

Answer (score 6):

In the Grub menu, select **Previous Linux Versions** to go to your list of previous kernels. The selection is just below the latest kernel in recovery mode.

To remove the kernel, execute in the Terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove 2.6.38.11.26
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

New kernels do not delete the older ones.
The last one (i guess 2.6.38.10) should still be there in your grub menu.
Just reboot and select that.

You might also want to install `startupmanager` which can be seen at fossfreedom's link, which will provide an easy GUI to change the default kernel to the working one.

Comment: Be careful with `startupmanager`! It's a very good tool for very quickly ruining your bootloader if you alter things like resolutions. I would go as far to say don't use it unless you have a LiveCD lying around (so you can chroot and fix things if you bork them)