# ubuntu 14.04 freezes randomly

Tags: freeze

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 version along side with windows 7.
Ubuntu freezes randomly I am unable to use any keys on keyboard since they are not working even mouse is not working.the only solution to get off from this freeze is restarting my computer.I have ATi/AMD graphic card but I removed it before installing Ubuntu 14.04.I have run memory test no problem with ram.please give some solution to get rid of this abnormal freeze. thanks in advance.

system configuration

1. CPU=Intel core 2 duo e7500 2.93ghz
2. motherboard=Intel dg41wv
3. hard disk=Seagate 500gb
4. ram=4gb

   I dual booted windows 7 and 12.04 LTS version.in 12.04 I am getting freezes frequently so reinstalled by formatting whole computer and installing windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 but still freezes are frequently occurring.then I formatted whole system again installed windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 still I am getting random freezes..I am using GCC compiler,vim editor and Firefox no other applications

Comment: Similar thing happens to me too, but I wait for some time (30-60 seconds) and it usually unfreezes. dmesg and syslog don't show anything... :(

Comment: Possible solution from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above post. This post addresses persistent freezing and how to find a long-term remedy to that. The other post addresses how to reboot your computer should it freeze, which is not a long-term solution to persistent freezing.

Answer (score 0):

use the following commands:- While holding `alt`+ `prtSc` + `R E I S U B`.

R:  Switch to XLATE mode
E:  Send Terminate signal to all processes except for init
I:  Send Kill signal to all processes except for init
S:  Sync all mounted file-systems
U:  Remount file-systems as read-only
B:  Reboot

or try this:-

Enter `Ctrl+alt+F1` login there by user name and password.Now enter `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Comment: mouse and keyboard are completely not working.tried those options but no response from keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Even if this works, it won't fix the original problem, it will only do a software restart.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other submissions, I found this link to a [SOLVED] forum thread describing the same issue symptoms you are having:
http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f64/solved-how-to-identify-cause-of-linux-system-freeze-556981.html

that theorizes that the issue is related to improper system timing, linked to a cpu swap with no kernel update. Further trouble-shooting is beyond my experience level at present, but it's a start.

*Amended
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/855932
In the above listed link, and several others I found in my web travels, it is suggested that your issue may stem from a kernel regression. In consideration of other issues I've seen related to MTP inconsistencies, and the previously shown source related to kernel inconsistencies with hardware, your best bet may be to roll back your kernel to an earlier version, and upgrade again to current. This has been shown to solve MTP file-system issues, and *could* potentially remedy your intermittent freeze problem.

Please see [How Can I Roll Back a Kernel Update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57937/how-can-i-roll-back-a-kernel-update) for instructions on rolling back your kernel, and [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) for instructions on how to update it once again to current.

Comment: He has freeze when a particular application is running..in the above link you provided @sonofentropy

Comment: how to go back to earlier version of kernel.sorry I am so new to Ubuntu. help me

Comment: @rajesh chowdary, check the lower amended section of my post, with links for both rolling back and updating kernel.