# Problem with Display Resolutions after update

Tags: 14.10, display-resolution

After installing recommended updates my display configurations don't work.

I have a 27" Monitor and a laptop display.

Whenever I set the 27" Monitor to 1920x1080 the laptop display gets "Messed up"

The Display Settings will not allow me to move the launcher to the 27" monitor.

If I set the 27" Monitor to 1600x900 it works fine but still will not let me move the launcher.

If I turn the laptop display off it seems to work fine on the 27" display.

Comment: So I have continued to research this it appears that part of my problem is in the nvidia-settings it is only recognizing a single display and not 2 displays I think that this is effecting how the display renders.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, at least temporarily.

What appears to be the case is some how the the proprietary nvidia drivers do not work with kernel version 3.13.0.43 (at least in my case). This causes the computer to incorrectly identify the two monitors as being a single unit rather then two separate items.

I used the procedure in this post to roll back to 3.13.0.40 and everything works fine.

[How Can I Roll Back a Kernel Update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57937/how-can-i-roll-back-a-kernel-update)

I will have to wait for an updated driver before I can update my kernel.