# Can not boot after 14.04 to 14.04.1 update, but recovery boot works

Tags: boot, 14.04, recovery-mode

Recovery is the only way I can boot as ubuntu is my only os, I can reinstall, but would rather not.

I do not see the point in reinstalling the same os, to get the same issues. whenever I boot up or restart I don't get a logo or anything, just a backlit black screen. I have to pull power, restart, go to advanced options and select between normal boot which gives same result, and recovery which will work when I click on a couple repair options. I'm not very technical, and this is my wifes pc, she is not nearly as techy as I am, and I'm no coder. I seriously need help... I know nothing about grub. I know nothing about boot options. I have heard of something called nomodeset, and tried it.. nothing works.

Where can I get the official ubuntu 14.04 LTS, not 14.04.1. 14.04 LTS was perfect. I seriously regret the upgrade unless this boot/reboot issue can be solved.

Comment: for what time haven't you runned ´sudo apt-get update &&sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Try running boot-repair, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Answer (score 1):

#### Try an older kernel.

Rather than trying to run 14.04 without updates, I recommend trying to boot from an older kernel. You should still have at least one older kernel installed.

- [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)
  I recommend trying [this simple way](https://askubuntu.com/a/82144/22949) first--i.e., hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting and select a previous kernel version.

(I understand you may already have tried this, but if not, I recommend trying. And if you have multiple older kernels installed and have only tried some, I recommend trying the others.)

If that gives you a working system, you can change the default to the older kernel:

- [How to remove/ignore most recent kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40780/how-to-remove-ignore-most-recent-kernel)

The video/display problem.

> whenever I boot up or restart I don't get a logo or anything, just a backlit black screen.

Something here might help you:

- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
  (Particularly [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162078/22949), but I recommend browsing through all of them.)

And if you have an Nvidia video card, maybe this will help:

- [NVIDIA drivers not working after upgrade. Why can I only see terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37590/nvidia-drivers-not-working-after-upgrade-why-can-i-only-see-terminal)

#### Going back from 14.04 to 14.04.1 without updates.

> Where can I get the official ubuntu 14.04 LTS, not 14.04.1. 14.04 LTS was perfect.

You can download the original 14.04 iso images [from the releases server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/). To have that installed, you would have to reinstall it. You may be able to install the old versions of specific packages to fix your problem, but rolling back your entire installation is probably not feasible.

A possible temporary workaround is to run from a live environment while you're still sorting out the problem. (That is, you'd burn the ISO image to a CD/DVD or USB, and boot from that.)

The 14.04 ISOs are named with versions numbers as you'd expect. If you really need one of those original images, pick the the `desktop` image for your architecture (`i386` for 32-bit; `amd64` for 64-bit). The ones with `14.04.1` in their names are for the point release; the ones with just `14.04` are the original.

Here are the download links for each image, for convenience:

- [`ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso)
- [`ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)

You can then hold off updating (or updating particular packages) until the problem is resolved or you decide to work on it again. If course, not installing security updates can put you at risk. For that reason, you might wish to consider this a solution of somewhere near last resort.

#### Updating 14.04 turns it into 14.04.1.

If update your 14.04 system, it becomes a 14.04.1 system. Going from a release to its point releases is not like going between separate releases. That is, when 14.10 comes out, updating a 14.04.* system will not automatically upgrade it to 14.10; a release upgrade is a separate action.

But going from 14.04 to 14.04.1 is just a matter of installing available updates. Therefore, if you install updates in the Software Updater (which used to be called the Update Manager and is sometimes still referred to by that term), or by running a command like `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, that will turn your 14.04 system into a 14.04.1 system.

Usually that is a very good thing, but in your case, apparently one or more of the updates breaks your system.

You can still run `sudo apt-get update` (which just updates that information available to your package manager about what software is available for upgrade/installation), and you can still install individual updates in the Update Manager (make sure to uncheck what you don't want installed) or individual new or updated packages with `sudo apt-get install ...`.

If you configure your system to install updates automatically, it will automatically "turn back into" a 14.04 system.

Comment: I went with the 14.04 lte iso. Running fine now that I have, just have to do the touchups. Before uninstalling 14.04.1 I ran check disk for defects and immediately something called autorun was the first and only error found. Also checked disk for defects from usb, same result. Maybe the Ubuntu team can check into that, or if it is just PC specific. Im using an HP 15.. if that matters. Luckily I keep everything backed up to an external HD. Thank you for the detailed and informative response.

Comment: Alsomy wife has ordered windows 8.1 recover disks, is there any way I can install that alongside Ubuntu, and share disk space equally. I have tried gparted and other disk partitioning tools to no avail, the space used by one OS is.. locked down to say the least, and had to reinstall OS to gain functionality. As of now Ubuntu is my only OS, and used all disk space. I normally do not get an option to install OS alongside another. my Options are Delete other OS or something else, either way..something never goes right. How do I free up space?

Comment: will this cause me to upgrade to 14.04.1? sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @seamsterstacy *"Before uninstalling 14.04.1 I ran check disk for defects and immediately something called autorun was the first and only error found."* All official ISO images are tested before release; checking for defects is not to find bugs in Ubuntu, but to see if your install medium is good. The presence of *any* defect means your ISO file was corrupted during download or afterwards before you burned it to CD/DVD or wrote it to USB, or that the burn/write was done incorrectly or otherwise failed, or that the CD/DVD/USB was damaged afterwards, *[continued]*

Comment: *[continuing]* or the machine you're installing on has a bad CD/DVD drive (or the SCSI/IDE interface it uses is bad) or bad USB interface, or bad RAM, or other hardware problems. Usually it's a corrupted ISO download or incorrectly burned CD/DVD or incorrectly written USB. *Regarding your question about installing Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu:* When you install Ubuntu you should get an option to install alongside the existing OS. Windows does not provide that option, so you must shrink your Ubuntu partitions manually first. GParted must be run from a live CD/DVD or live USB.

Comment: @seamsterstacy If you're trying to install Ubuntu alongside an existing Windows system and the "alongside" option isn't shown, [see this](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962). If you're trying to resize partitions that have been created by Ubuntu (not Windows), [this explains how](http://askubuntu.com/q/126153). If you're trying to install Ubuntu on a system that already has, or shipped with, Windows 8, [this is how](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835). If you need more help with any of these topics that aren't the same as what you asked about in this question, I recommend posting a new question.

Comment: @seamsterstacy "will this cause me to upgrade to 14.04.1? sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" I've edited my answer to address that. In short, yes.